# CSS border-radius of a div:after pseudo element rendering wrong on first load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been playing around with changing an images color overlay, through the use of a div:after pseudo element, with matching border-radius.

https://jsbin.com/konopak/1/edit?html,output

You will notice on first load the background color is a solid square, but if you shift the frame, or change any element on the page it renders it properly. Is there a way to make it render properly on first load? Why is this happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <style>
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 90px;
    }

    .hero-image {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 200px;
      display: flex;
      background-color: #ff000050;
      /* border-radius: 90px; */
    }

    .hero-image:after {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: inherit;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      content: "";
      border-radius: 90px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<label id="color-label" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 18px; width: 18px; border-radius: 10px; cursor: crosshair;">
  <input id="color-tag" type="color" value="#ff0000" style="visibility: hidden;">
</label>

<div class="hero-image">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=400&w=400" id="cat" alt=""/>
</div>

<script>
  const label = document.getElementById('color-label');
  document.getElementById('color-tag').addEventListener('change', function () {
    label.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
    let imgDom = document.querySelector('.hero-image');
    imgDom.style.backgroundColor = this.value + '40';
    // imgDom[0].style.backgroundColor = this.value;
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent and remove the additional `border-radius` properties and `display: flex` which is causing the display issue in safari.

I suggest making a few updates as per below to help with image scaling too:

```
 img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .hero-image {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 200px;
      max-height: 200px;
      background-color: #ff000050;
      border-radius: 90px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .hero-image:after {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: inherit;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      content: "";
    }
```

The container parent's radius + overflow should be all that's needed and the additional child properties are superfluous.

[JSbin update](https://jsbin.com/qosuzobiyo/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to get overflow hidden to work, but couldn't get the right combination. Without the border-radius it does nothing. Any idea why I can't adjust width/height of the color-label?

Comment: Simply change the label from being an inline element to a block element:  [Updated Bin](https://jsbin.com/tuceyinoxa/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: To confirm, you are not removing `border-radius` entirely - just set it on the parent as per the sample code.

Comment: I still wonder why when i move the frame it actually removes the excess in my first example. It's some weird bug or drawing order of operation.

Comment: Its the display: flex which is not needed, I'll update and fix a few things for you

Comment: Another question. I've spent a long time trying to figure out how to use javascript to set the attributes of a pseudo element, still haven't found an answer. Claims that you can't do it from years ago. Maybe something recent has made it possible?

Comment: Just add/remove classes that contain the pseudo elements. See [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property

Comment: Now im trying to get the click action from img to trigger input from the color picker, onclick="document.getElementById('color-tag').click()"  but it's not working.

Comment: @Teebu please accept the answer and post a new question if there is a new, unrelated problem. SO is designed to deal with a focussed question at a time so it's clear for users.  Happy to look at what you have done there

Comment: Done. I actually figured it out. The hero div was intercepting my click. Thanks for your help.